# Car is shaking, feels like the car doesn't have as much power, gear knob also shaking and exhaust smells of fuel (and was louder than usual)

Tags: engine, clutch, nissan, manual-transmission

Okay so the car is a Nissan 200SX S15 and as i'm relatively new to the 
manual transmission I wanted to practice hill starting (which is where I screwed
up). I pretty much let go of the clutch way too quick and it immediately stalled the car and shut it down.

After I got it up over the hill the second time the car and gear knob started to shake and i felt the car was making less power and couldn't reach higher rpms even at low gear. As i parked the car the exhaust smelt like fuel. So i'd like to know what happened and how I can fix it if possible. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like its misfiring on a cylinder? possibly check the spark plugs as a first port of call.

Comment: Are you sure that the car was actually in a lower gear when you got to the top of the hill?  If you skipped into a higher gear while shifting and didn't give it enough gas it can cause the car to shake and make less power than expected

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you stalled the car uphill and that it is acting that have most likely nothing in common.

Gear knob vibration is quite normal on older cars. Also, when car is on low RPM under load, vibrations tend to be more prominent in manual transmission cars.

Start with driving the car on the flat surface to see if it's accelerating as expected. If the exhaust smells with fuel, it is most likely running rich, whcih can be caused by the following:

**Fueling**

- Injectors might be leaking flooding one of the cylinders.

**Spark**

- Spark plugs are old, improperly gaped, soaked with fuel.
- Coils are old, damaged.

**Sensors**

- primary O2 sensor is faulty

Your best bet is to join car-specific forum like one below and those guys might have a common problem/solution for you.

[s15 Club](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTgOGL4azMAhUL3WMKHSlCCO0QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.s15oc.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNG9pwc3UIf0G4RqDfVJRSz5NCs8Mg&sig2=uEsNMbHqvkKB9E8UX2kTZA)